# How is the precision loss from integer to float defined in C++?

Tags: c++, floating-point, rounding, static-cast

I've a question to the code snippet below:

```
long l=9223372036854775807L;
float f=static_cast<float>(l);
```

The long value cannot be represanted exactly according to the IEEE754.

My Question is how is the lossy conversion handled:

1. Is the nearest floating point representation taken?
2. Is the next smaller/bigger representation taken?
3. Or is an other approach is taken?

I'm aware of this question
[what happens at background when convert int to float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7977265/what-happens-at-background-when-convert-int-to-float) but this does not anwser my question.

Comment: C++ does not mandate IEEE754, FYI.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

C++ defines the conversion like this (quoting latest standard draft):

> [conv.fpint]
>
> A prvalue of an integer type or of an unscoped enumeration type can be converted to a prvalue of a floating-point type.
> The result is exact if possible.
> If the value being converted is in the range of values that can be represented but the value cannot be represented exactly, it is an implementation-defined choice of either the next lower or higher representable value.
> *[ Note: Loss of precision occurs if the integral value cannot be represented exactly as a value of the floating-point type.
> — end note
> ]*
> If the value being converted is outside the range of values that can be represented, the behavior is undefined.
> If the source type is bool, the value false is converted to zero and the value true is converted to one.

The IEEE 754 standard defines conversion like this:

> 5.4.1 Arithmetic operations
>
> It   shall   be   possible   to   convert   from   all   supported   signed   and   unsigned   integer   formats   to   all supported   arithmetic   formats.   Integral   values  are   converted   exactly   from   integer   formats   to floating-point formats whenever the value is representable in both formats. If the converted value is   not   exactly  representable   in  the  destination   format,   the   result   is   determined   according  to   the applicable rounding-direction attribute, and an inexact or floating-point overflow exception arises as   specified   in   Clause 7, just as with arithmetic operations. The signs of integer zeros are preserved. Integer zeros without signs are converted to +0. The preferred exponent is 0.

Rounding modes are specified as:

> 4.3.1 Rounding-direction attributes to nearest
>
> - roundTiesToEven,   the   floating-point   number   nearest   to   the   infinitely   precise   result   shall   be delivered;   if   the   two   nearest   floating-point   numbers   bracketing   an   unrepresentable   infinitely precise result are equally near, the one with an even least significant digit shall be delivered.
> - roundTiesToAway,   the   floating-point   number   nearest   to   the   infinitely   precise   result   shall   be delivered;   if   the   two   nearest   floating-point   numbers   bracketing   an   unrepresentable   infinitely precise result are equally near, the one with larger magnitude shall be delivered.
>
> 4.3.2 Directed rounding attributes
>
> - roundTowardPositive, the result shall be the format’s floating-point number (possibly +∞) closest to and no less than the infinitely precise result
> - roundTowardNegative, the result shall be the format’s floating-point number (possibly −∞) closest to and no greater than the infinitely precise result
> - roundTowardZero, the result shall be the format’s floating-point number closest to and no greater in magnitude than the infinitely precise result.
>
> 4.3.3 Rounding attribute requirements
>
> The   roundTiesToEven   rounding-direction   attribute   shall   be   the   default   rounding-direction   attribute   for results in binary formats.

So by default, your suggestion 1 would apply, but only if another mode hasn't been selected.

---

The C++ standard library inherits `<cfenv>` from the C standard. This header offers macros, functions and types for interacting with the floating point environment, including the rounding modes.

Answer (score 6):

See [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion):

> A prvalue of integer or unscoped enumeration type can be converted to
>   a prvalue of any floating-point type. If the value cannot be
>   represented correctly, it is implementation defined whether the
>   closest higher or the closest lower representable value will be
>   selected, although if IEEE arithmetic is supported, rounding defaults
>   to nearest. If the value cannot fit into the destination type, the
>   behavior is undefined. If the source type is bool, the value false is
>   converted to zero, and the value true is converted to one.

As for the rounding rules of IEEE 754, there seem to be [five of them](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Rounding_rules). I couldn't find any information on which ones are used in which situation, though. It looks like it's up to the implementation however, you can set the rounding mode in a C++ program as described [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/fenv/feround).